# VBA Lotus Notes attachment wont send when using both Richtext and MIME

Tags: excel, vba, lotus-notes, mime, rtf

I have code that essentially sends an email, it creates the email with a MIME HTML body and a Richtext PDF attachment. The weird part is, is that when the message is saved, both the HTML Body is there and the attachment at the top are both present.

When I send this out externally the PDF attachment is no longer there. If I comment out the HTML MIME part of the code the attachment sends attached at the top externally just fine.

Why is one preventing the other and how would I get both to send the same way the document is saved?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Public Sub COM_Email_Send()

Dim NSession As Object
Dim NMailDb As Object
Dim NDocument As Object
Dim NBody As Object
Dim NChild As Object
Dim Nstream As Object
Dim RichTextHeader As Object

Dim i As Long
Dim Row As Long
Dim Recipient As String
Dim File As String
Dim attachmentFile As String
Dim Data As String
Dim AttachedOb As Object
Dim EmbedOb As Object
Dim NHeader As Object
Dim strFileType As Variant
Dim MIMEDoc As Object

Set NSession = CreateObject("Lotus.NotesSession")
Call NSession.Initialize("password")

Set NMailDb = NSession.GetDatabase("directory", "server")
If Not NMailDb.IsOpen = True Then
Call NMailDb.Open
End If

    Row = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 1 To Row
    
    Recipient = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i)
    
    If Recipient <> "" Then
    
    
    File = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value
    
    attachmentFile = "Directory" & File
    
    Data = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy")


    Set NDocument = NMailDb.CreateDocument
    Set Nstream = NSession.CreateStream
    
    
    Call NDocument.replaceitemvalue("Form", "Memo")
    Call NDocument.replaceitemvalue("SendTo", Recipient)
    Call NDocument.replaceitemvalue("Subject", "Please see your clearance documents attached " & Data)
    Call NDocument.replaceitemvalue("Sender", "noreply@test.com")
    
    If attachmentFile <> "" Then
    Set AttachedOb = NDocument.Createrichtextitem("attachmentFile")
    Set EmbedOb = AttachedOb.embedobject(1454, "", attachmentFile, "")
    End If
    
    Call Nstream.Open("Directory\HTML BODY.htm")
    Set NBody = NDocument.CreateMIMEEntity '("memo")
    Set RichTextHeader = NBody.CreateHeader("Content-Type")
    Call RichTextHeader.SetHeaderVal("multipart/mixed")
    Set MIMEDoc = NBody.CreateChildEntity()
    
    Call MIMEDoc.SetContentFromBytes(Nstream, "text/html", ENC_IDENTITY_BINARY)
    Call Nstream.Close
    
    
    
    NDocument.savemessageonsend = True
    
    Call NDocument.replaceitemvalue("PostedDate", Now())
    Call NDocument.Send(False)
    

    Set NDocument = Nothing
    Set Nstream = Nothing
    
    End If
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

*Edited code Following Richards guidance

```
Public Sub COM_Email_Send()

Dim NSession As Object
Dim NMailDb As Object
Dim NDocument As Object
Dim NBody As Object
Dim NChild As Object
Dim Nstream As Object
Dim Header As Object
Dim HeaderChild As Object


Dim i As Long
Dim Row As Long
Dim Recipient As String
Dim File As String
Dim attachmentFile As String
Dim Data As String
Dim AttachedOb As Object
Dim EmbedOb As Object
Dim NHeader As Object
Dim strFileType As Variant
Dim MIMEDoc As Object

Set NSession = CreateObject("Lotus.NotesSession")
Call NSession.Initialize("password")

Set NMailDb = NSession.GetDatabase("server directory", "server")
If Not NMailDb.IsOpen = True Then
Call NMailDb.Open
End If

    Row = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 1 To Row
    
    Recipient = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i)
    
    If Recipient <> "" Then
    
    
    File = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value
    
    attachmentFile = "Directory" & File
    
    Data = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy")


    Set NDocument = NMailDb.CreateDocument
    Set Nstream = NSession.CreateStream
    
    
    Call NDocument.replaceitemvalue("Form", "Memo")
    Call NDocument.replaceitemvalue("SendTo", Recipient)
    Call NDocument.replaceitemvalue("Subject", "Please see your clearance documents attached " & Data)
    Call NDocument.replaceitemvalue("Sender", "noreply@test.com")
    
    Set NBody = NDocument.CreateMIMEEntity
    
    Call Nstream.Open("Directory")
    
    Set MIMEDoc = NBody.CreateChildEntity()
    Set Header = MIMEDoc.Createheader("Content-Type")
    Call Header.SetHeaderVal("multipart/mixed")
    
    Call MIMEDoc.SetContentFromBytes(Nstream, "text/html", ENC_IDENTITY_BINARY)
    Call Nstream.Close
    Call Nstream.Truncate
    
    
    Call Nstream.Open("Directory" & File)
    Set NChild = NBody.CreateChildEntity()
    
    Set HeaderChild = NChild.Createheader("Content-Type")
    Call HeaderChild.SetHeaderVal("multipart/mixed")
    
    Set HeaderChild = NChild.Createheader("Content-Disposition")
    Call HeaderChild.SetHeaderVal("attachment; filename=" & File)
    
    Set HeaderChild = NChild.Createheader("Content-ID")
    Call HeaderChild.SetHeaderVal(File)
    
    Set HeaderChild = NChild.Createheader("Content-Transfer-Encoding")
    Call HeaderChild.SetHeaderVal(base64)
    
    Call NChild.SetContentFromBytes(Nstream, "application/pdf", ENC_BASE64)
    
    Call Nstream.Close
    
    
    NDocument.savemessageonsend = True
    
    Call NDocument.replaceitemvalue("PostedDate", Now())
    
    
    Call NDocument.Send(False)
    

    Set NDocument = Nothing
    Set Nstream = Nothing
    
    End If
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Document now attaches as PDF below the HTML body but is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An email message can either be built with Notes Rich Text or with MIME. It can't be built with both.

If you want to send both, you will have to construct a multipart/mixed message (a parent NotesMIME entity with multipart/mixed for the content-type, like you have above, but it needs to have two child NotesMIMEEntity parts. One child NotesMIMEEntity will be for the text/HTML content -- it will need its own content-type set to text/html. The second child NotesMIMEEntity will be for the attachment. You will have to read the attachment data from the file and encode it as base64. You can find a LotusScript function that does base64 encoding [here](https://www.nsftools.com/tips/Base64v14.lss).  Then you will set the content of the child entity from the base64 data, and set the headers for this with appropriate info for the file. E.g., if it is a PDF you are going to want  MIME headers that look something like this:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf; name="MyPDFFile.pdf"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="MyPDFFile.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

For most other file types, I think application/octet-stream is what you will want, but it's been a while and there could be other type/subtype combinations available. Whenever I have any questions about what MIME headers should look like, I manually send an email to my gmail account containing an example of the content that I want and use the 'show original' feature to examine the tree structure and details of the headers.

Comment: I have attached it with the guidance above but the document itself is just blank, correct amount of pages mind you, but still blank. It opens up fine locally from the sent box but not externally.

Comment: Send a manual example by hand and compare the MIME headers and content to what your code sends. The difference will tell you where to look for your problem.

Comment: Hmm looks like a pdf I sent myself has x-attachment-ID which I'm not quite sure yet what that does but also the Current-transfer-encoding I have declared within ```setcontentfrombytes``` doesn't seem to have picked up and isn't being shown. Is there some other way I could declare the encoding?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out, Thanks Richard